# Pound sign shows up in my URL when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Not sure this is the place to ask this question but here I go.

Now if I click the the source link it displays the pound sign in the URL how can I stop the pound sign from showing up in the URL? Can some one show me what changes I need to make to my jQuery or HTML code?

Here is the HTML:

```
<li><label for="tutorial-summary">Tutorial Summary: <a href="#" class="code-editor">source</a> <a href="#" class="text-editor">wysiwyg</a></label></li>         
<li><textarea rows="10" cols="20" name="summary" id="tutorial-summary"></textarea></li>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.code-editor').click(function(){
        $('#tutorial-content').ckeditorGet().destroy();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Instead of `return false` you should define the event as a parameter your function and use [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

Answer (score 1):

You can add the JavaScript void() function to each link if possible

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="code-editor">source</a>
```

I tested Rich Answer.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.code-editor').click(function(event){
        $('#tutorial-content').ckeditorGet().destroy();
        event.preventDefault(event);
    });
});
```

And for some reason I still got the hash sign in url I hope my answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the attribute `href="#"` and adjust the style sheet so that the `<a>` element has the desired appearance (removing the attribute prevents it from getting link styles but you can specify underlining, blue color, hand cursor etc. if you want them).

By “pound sign” you presumably mean the number sign “#” (which may look like “£” on antique devices). It appears in the URL because you have a link with the relative URL reference “#”, so just don’t use a link – modern browsers treat an `<a>` element as clickable even when it is not a link.

Answer (score 0):

You're not stopping the click event in your function. Add the following line to the top or the bottom of your click function handler and you'll be fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.code-editor').click(function(event){
        $('#tutorial-content').ckeditorGet().destroy();
        event.preventDefault(event);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you should use the JQuery method `event.preventDefault();` I tested it and it works. I hope it works for you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.code-editor').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#tutorial-content').ckeditorGet().destroy();
    });
});
```